# Dns fail in Bluetooth tethering?

Tags: bluetooth, internet, bluetooth-tethering

When I connect my laptop with my phone over Bluetooth tethering,
I do not get internet access, however wifi and usb tethering is working fine?

There is a dns fail, I checked using **dig** command,

Comment: Trying changing dns

Comment: I tried , but the same dns is working over wifi or usb tethering